# Alternater color in row GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a GridView with X elements.

My gridview has a 2 columns. I need color per row

```
[0] [1] - Color White
[2] [3] - Color Black
[4] [5] - Color White
[6] [6] - Color Black
```

I'm try this in adapter, But the result was not what was expected.

```
if (position %  numColuns == 0) {       
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white));
else 
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black));
```

I'm try too, change rotate my gridview using this properties:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

Anyone have a idea? Thanks.

**Edit - SOLUTION**

```
if ((position /  numColuns) %  2 == 0) 
//color black
else 
color white
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row number using position / num columns. Then check if the row number has changed each time in the onbindview holder. If changed, u can change the color else use the previous color for the background.